# Delete whole line which has specific words using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, rss, preg-replace

I have rss reader and want to delete one line which has specific words from description.

For example, I want to delete line which have that words "this text is from"

My code:

```
$xml=("http://rss-feed");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
//echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
//  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
//echo("<br>");
//echo($channel_desc . "</p>");
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=20; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p><a target=_blank href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
  echo ("<hr>");
}
```

Comment: So what happens with this code? You tagged `preg_replace` are you using that? Having an example of `$xml` would be useful.

Comment: this $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description') . description have url for thread and it is dynamic url . i want to delete line which has dynamic url. preg_replace if static line and line has dynamic url.

Comment: I don't think that your code is very relevant for your question. You should add to it an example of xml code. As an aside you should learn about XPath, that, in my opinion, will solve most of your problems.